# Python pandas fast way to Insert row into DF with missing values as Nan

Tags: python, pandas, insert

I am looking for a fast way to insert a `df_row` (dataframe with only 1 row, and column could be less than 24) into a `df_master` (dataframe with few thousand rows and 24 columns)

for example:

```
df_row
A B C D E F G .... H
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 .... 8

df_master
A B C D ........................... Y
```

I am looking for a fast way to insert df_row into `df_master`, and set `NaN` for the columns that do no exist in `df_row`.

Previously, I was doing

```
df_master = df_master.append(df_row)
```

But this method gets slower as `df_master` gets better.

Is there a fast way of doing **inplace** append?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement), but need convert `df1` to `Series` - e.g. by selecting by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
d = {'F': {0: 6}, 'D': {0: 4}, 'B': {0: 2}, 'C': {0: 3}, 
'A': {0: 1}, 'E': {0: 5}, 'G': {0: 7}, 'H': {0: 8}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[10,20,30,40]], columns=list('ACDE'))
print (df1)
    A   C   D   E
0  10  20  30  40

df.loc[len(df.index)] = df1.iloc[0]
print (df)
       A    B     C     D     E    F    G    H
 0   1.0  2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
 1  10.0  NaN  20.0  30.0  40.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: It looks like its not appending properly. I only see 1 record at the end of my function. I should be seeing 100

Comment: Is there a faster way to append? This method is still too slow... When the DF gets bigger (few hundred thousand records), its taking 5 seconds to insert 100 records.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you need append only one row.

Comment: If need append 100 row, better is use one big df with 100 rows and then append only once.

Comment: Yes, but what Im trying to say is, the speed of append depends on the size of the DF... Is there a way to append in constant speed?

Comment: Your answer was helpful, but its still too slow.... I need something even faster.

Comment: Hmmm, so is not possible create list of all small df in loop `df_all = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, dfn])` and then append? It should be faster. Or there is some problem with it?